# WordPress image with pre-installed plugins using Dockerfile

Tags: wordpress, docker, plugins, dockerfile

Copying plugin folder to WordPress default image directory and creating a new image. Pushing it to the repository on Docker Hub, then pull back image and run the container, but the plugin is not installed. Folder is not found in the container.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  wp:
    image: "arslanliaqat/wordpresswithplugin:1.0"
    volumes:
      - './wordpress:/var/www/html'
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: qwerty
  mysql:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: qwerty
    volumes:  
      - "my-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql"
volumes: 
  my-datavolume:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM wordpress:php7.1-apache

COPY preferred-languages /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/preferred-languages/
```

could not pre-install plugin

Answer (score 3):

So this is what's happening:

When you are building your custom image, you add the plugin folder `/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/preferred-languages/` and that works just fine.

You can test that by simply running `docker run -it --rm arslanliaqat/wordpresswithplugin sh` and `cd /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins` and you should see the folder.

The reason the folder is missing when you are using your docker-compose.yml file is because you are mounting the volume "over" the folder that's already there. Try removing the volumes declaration from wp service in the docker-compose.yml file and then you should be able to see your plugin folder.

I would suggest you use the wordpress:php7.1-apache for your wp service and mount your plugin folder the same way you are mounting wordpress

Example:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  wp:
    image: "wordpress:php7.1-apache"
    volumes:
      - './wordpress:/var/www/html'
      - './preferred-languages:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/preferred-languages'
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: qwerty
  mysql:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: qwerty
    volumes:  
      - "my-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql"
volumes: 
  my-datavolume:
```

Is there a specific reason you need the plugin to be in the image already?

---

**UPDATED**

I created a simple gist which should accomplish what you want to do. The entrypoint lacks checks for already existing theme/plugin directories etc, but this should serve as POC

https://gist.github.com/karlisabe/16c0ccc52bdf34bee5f201ac7a0c45f7

Comment: I personally like to bake my plugins into my image. That way, if I get hacked, I can delete the container and restore to a good known version. The downside is that plugin upgrades need an image rebuild and re-deploy.

Comment: Well you can always use a custom entrypoint script for your image that creates a symlink from a different folder on the image to the plugins folder... If this sounds like an option I can add an example to the answer

Comment: what i actually want is that when i install wordpress, my theme, plugins are automatically installed.

Comment: I am not really a WP developer, but as far as I remember plugins/themes can include DB changes as well, so that means you also need to run some script that installs those? Or you simply need the plugin/theme files in the necessary locations?

I'd say you can create a simple bash script to use as entry point for your image, which creates a symlink from the theme/plugin folder to the necessary WP subfolder on startup

Comment: @KārlisĀbele the plugin folder is visible now. but its contents are empty and its also not shown in the wordpress plugin table.

Comment: Ok... And from what I've seen in the Dockerfile and the docker-entrypoint.sh of wordpress docker image, it's going to be quite difficult to do this. 

I created a simple gist for this, you can try to use this approach and it should work fine
https://gist.github.com/karlisabe/16c0ccc52bdf34bee5f201ac7a0c45f7

Comment: while running this gist, getting this error  : ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo': No such file or directory

Comment: It looks like the wordpress folder was not mounted to the container. Can you share the docker-compose.yml you used and the folder structure you have?